# How can I combine two datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm new to VB.net. I want to combine two datagridviews, I get those two data from a CSV file. For example I have Datagridview1:

```
  Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        readFileName = "LNU010F" & "_" & dateParam.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
        sr = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Documents and Settings\ucpb\Desktop\Sample CSV data\" + readFileName)
        Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(11)), New DataColumn(newline(48))})

        While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
            newline = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)
            Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            newrow.ItemArray = {newline(11), newline(48)}                
            dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
        End While

        DataGridViewCSV1.DataSource = dt
```

This is what I get from the first code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaJZ1.png

I have Datagridview2:

```
 Dim delimeter As String = txtDelimiter.Text
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        fileName = txtName.Text & "_" & dateParam.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
        readFileName = txtName.Text & "_" & dateParam.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & ".csv"
        fileReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Documents and Settings\ucpb\Desktop\Sample CSV data\" + readFileName)

        Dim readColumn As String = fileReader.ReadLine
        Dim splitColumn As String() = readColumn.Split(delimeter)

        For Each arr As String In splitColumn
            dt.Columns.Add(arr)
        Next

        Dim readRow As String = fileReader.ReadLine
        Dim splitRow As String()

        While readRow <> ""
            splitRow = readRow.Split(delimeter)

            dt.Rows.Add(splitRow)
            readRow = fileReader.ReadLine()
        End While

        DataGridViewCSV2.DataSource = dt
```

This is what I get from the second code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0SmT.png

What I want is to add the **UID**(Datagridview1) at the end of the Datagridview2. **Acctno** is the key, Datagridview2 should have the same UID as in the first datagridview because the data is not properly arranged in the datagridview2. Any answer would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How does the data come in? We need more details. Maybe some code attempt.

Comment: What do you mean, "combine two datagridview", they are different data?  You should be able to figure this out, you alread add rows manually do this `Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow` and this `dt.Rows.Add(newrow)`. You just need to continue doing that for the next file.

Comment: DataTable has a Merge method

Comment: @Steve yes they are from different data. Acctno is my primary key to merge those data.